# Identity Server Dashboard

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, duende

I'm building an authentication system using ASP.NET and Duende Identity Server, and I have two projects. The first project is the server, which handles login requests, and the second is the dashboard where you can manage clients, API resources, users, roles, etc. (similar to the Auth0 dashboard).

The problem I'm encountering is how to use the DbContext of the Identity Server without registering it in the dashboard's Program.cs. When I attempted to do this, users couldn't log in to the dashboard. What happened was that the user would be redirected to the login page, fill in their credentials, get redirected back to the dashboard, but still be marked as an unauthenticated user, and their claims wouldn't be recognized.

im thinking about creating an api and consume it in the dashboard

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.